# QGraphicsScene. Как в pyqt5 нарисовать закрашенный эллипс?

Tags: python, python-3.x, qt, pyqt5, рисование

Каким образом на pyqt5 можно сделать эллипс закрашенным?
Вроде бы это делается через setBrush, но не пойму как.

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore, QtGui


class ExampleApp(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, design.Ui_MainWindow):
    def Plot(self):
        scene = QtWidgets.QGraphicsScene()
        self.graphicsView.setScene(scene)
        side = int(self.txt_size_square.text())
        r = QtCore.QRectF(QtCore.QPointF(x,y), QtCore.QSizeF(side, side))

        scene.addEllipse(r, QtGui.QPen(QtCore.Qt.green))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нужно было просто в `addEllipse` передавать параметр с `QBrush`:

```
from PyQt5 import Qt


class MainWindow(Qt.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.scene = Qt.QGraphicsScene()

        self.graphics_view = Qt.QGraphicsView()
        self.graphics_view.setScene(self.scene)

        self.setCentralWidget(self.graphics_view)

    def plot(self):
        rect = Qt.QRectF(0, 0, 90, 90)
        color = Qt.Qt.green

        self.scene.addEllipse(rect, Qt.QPen(color), Qt.QBrush(color))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = Qt.QApplication([])

    mw = MainWindow()
    mw.show()

    mw.plot()

    app.exec()
```

Скриншот:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

**PS.** `addEllipse` перегруженная функция и позволяет сразу указывать цвет, а не `QBrush`:

```
self.scene.addEllipse(rect, Qt.QPen(color), color)
```

**PPS.** альтернативой `addEllipse` будет метод `addItem`, но тогда нужно будет вручную создавать [эллипс](http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/QGraphicsEllipseItem.html):

```
item = Qt.QGraphicsEllipseItem(rect)
item.setPen(Qt.QPen(color))
item.setBrush(color)
self.scene.addItem(item)
```